# arraylist within an array java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Im new to java and would be great if someone could just point me in the right direction here.

Im trying to put different arraylists into one array so i can then put those array objects into a Jlist.

I have got so far but now just cant seem to populate my Jlist with what i want.

Any Pointers would be great.

```
private void btnCheckActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

carmakes[] makes = new carmakes[3];
Audi [0] = new carmakes (AudiFeatures);
BMW [1] = new carmakes (BMWFeatures);

        DefaultListModel myModel = new DefaultListModel();
        myModel.addElement(makes);
        lbxCarMake.setModel(myModel);

// Create Car
    ArrayList<String> AudiFeatures = new ArrayList<String>();
        AudiFeatures.add("Leather Seats");
        AudiFeatures.add("Bose Sound System");
        AudiFeatures.add("Paint Job");
        AudiFeatures.add("24inch Alloys");
            ProductOrder Audi  = new ProductOrder ("Audi",       (String)cbxenginesize.getSelectedItem(), AudiFeatures, 9999.99);

    //Create Car
    ArrayList<String> BMWFeatures = new ArrayList<String>();
        BMWFeatures.add("SatNav");
        BMWFeatures.add("Leather Seats");
        BMWFeatures.add("22inch Alloys");
            ProductOrder BMW = new ProductOrder ("BMW", (String) cbxenginesize.getSelectedItem(), BMWFeatures, 10000.99);
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You should read a tutorial on how to use arrays in Java.

Comment: Have a look at classes, inheritance, polimorphism in java it will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Before you even get to populating a `JList`...

```
 carmakes[] makes = new carmakes[3];
 Audi [0] = new carmakes (AudiFeatures);
 BMW [1] = new carmakes (BMWFeatures);
```

This needs to be moved further down the method until **after** `AudiFeatures` and `BMWFeatures` have been created. And it should be something more like this:

```
 carmakes[] makes = new carmakes[3];
 carmakes [0] = new carmakes ("Audi", AudiFeatures);
 carmakes [1] = new carmakes ("BMW", BMWFeatures);
```

or maybe you want to use a `HashMap` instead of an array, so that you can look up car makes by name.

Comment: Thanks i did think that, but thought it wouldn't matter until i called the array lists. What should i declare the array as will [] int work? or should it be something else?

Comment: Oh dear, you *really* need to read an array tutorial, and do some simpler exercises until you understand them better. It's like learning  a craft - you have to make simple things first.